# How to modify the incoming call view on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to modify the labels that the spring board shows on the view of an incoming call (e.g adding city info). My app does not need to be uploaded to the AppStore, but has to work on a device without jailbreak. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it without jailbreaking.